# Is there any reason to choose Flink over Spark 2.3 Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, spark-structured-streaming

Are there any benefits choosing Flink over the new Spark 2.3 for streaming applications, now when Spark 2.3 Brings ‘Continuous Processing’ with 1ms latency?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons I'd choose Flink is that Spark Structured Streaming 2.3 still doesn't have connectors to AWS Kinesis.
Also the new ‘Continuous Processing’ mode is very new and still doesn't support aggregates as shown [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/03/20/low-latency-continuous-processing-mode-in-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-3-0.html). We can expect support for that in maybe 6-12 months.
Lastly, Flink was built from ground up to do streaming while Spark was adapted. So Flink still has lower latency and richer API's.